# CSS Steps() with changes in duration

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I do not know if this is possible with css animations... I am attempting to animate a sprite using steps() but have certain frames last longer than others (frame #1 .5s, frame #2 .2s, frame #3 - #5 .1s, etc.). I tried to use multiple step animations but that didnt seem to work.  Any ideas?

```
@keyframes throw{
    100% {background-position: 380px;}
}
@keyframes hold{
    100% {background-position: 760px;}
}
@keyframes drop{
    100% {background-position: 1520px;}
}


#cheerleader{
    position:absolute
    top: 110px;
    left: 15%;
    width: 190px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url("/assets/images/cheer01.png") left center;
    animation:
        throw .5s steps(1, 2) infinite,
        hold .2s steps(3, 4),
        drop .8s steps(5, 8),
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

My updated code is this:

```
@keyframes hold{
    0% { background-position-x: 0px;  }
    100% {background-position-x: 160px;  }
}
@keyframes grab{
    0% {background-position-x: 160px; }
    100% {background-position-x: 480px; }
}
@keyframes propped{
    0% {background-position-x: 480px;}
    100% {background-position-x: 800px;}
}
@keyframes throw{
    0% {background-position-x: 800px;}
    100% {background-position-x: 960px;}
}
@keyframes catch{
    0% {background-position-x: 960px;}
    100% {background-position-x: 1280px;}
}

.cheerpeopleone{
    position:absolute;
    top:110px;
    left:15%;
    width:160px;
    height:320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('/assets/images/cheerpeopleone.png') left center;
    animation: 
        hold 0.5s steps(1) infinite,
        grab 0.3s steps(3) infinite,
        propped 0.6s steps(2) infinite, 
        throw 0.2s steps(1) infinite, 
        catch 0.3s steps(3) infinite; 
    animation-delay: 0s, .5s, 0.8s, 1.4s, 1.6s;
    z-index:90;
}
```

But now I am having the issue of the delay not working when it plays infinitely.  I also think there is something going on with my positioning since the figures slide into frame and then animate.  The full width of the png is 1280px and each frame is 160px wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It can be done with pure CSS animations. I have created a demo with 6 frames in total where the first two frames last 2s, next 2 frames last for 0.5s and the final 2 frames for 3s.
Also you can adjust `animation-delay` as per your requirement.

```css
@keyframes throw{
    0% { background-position: 0;  }
    100% {background-position: -512px;  }
}
@keyframes hold{
    0% {background-position: -512px; }
    100% {background-position: -1024px; }
}
@keyframes drop{
    0% {background-position: -1024px;}
    100% {background-position: -1280px;}
}


#cheerleader{
    position:absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 15%;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url("https://cdn.codeandweb.com/blog/2016/05/10/how-to-create-a-sprite-sheet/spritestrip.png") left center;
     -webkit-animation: throw 2s steps(2) forwards,
        hold 0.5s steps(2) forwards,
        drop 3s steps(1) forwards; 
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 2s, 2.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="cheerleader"></div>
```

Comment: I was curious if it is possible to have the animation run infinite rather than forwards?  I attempted this on my own and the animation delay stopped working after the first iteration.